# how can I store and access data attributes on elements like select options in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I would like to get the data attribute from option using react but for some reason I am unable and I am getting null.

```
<select onChange={(e) => this.onIndustryChangeOption(e)} value={this.props.selectedIndustry}>
    <option value="" data-industry="industry1">Select Industry</option>
    <option value="" data-industry="industry2">Select Industry 2</option>
</select>

onIndustryChangeOption(event, index, value) {
   console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-industry'));
   this.props.setRootState({selectedIndustry: event.target.value});
}
```

This is not working, I am sure there should be some other way of doing this!

Comment: why don't you use `value` attr ?

Comment: Your `onchange` event is for the select not the options, `event.target` is going to be the select element. You would need to use the select properties / methods to find the selected option and go from there.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk I would like to store an object into the attribute, is it possible to store objects into value? if so this makes it even easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`event.target` is the **`select`**, not the `option`. You need to get the `option`:

```
onIndustryChangeOption(event, index, value) {
  const {target} = event;
  const option = target.options[target.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    console.log(option.getAttribute('data-industry'));
    //this.props.setRootState({selectedIndustry: event.target.value});
  }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <select onChange={(e) => this.onIndustryChangeOption(e)} value={this.props.selectedIndustry}>
        <option value="" data-industry="industry1">Select Industry</option>
        <option value="" data-industry="industry2">Select Industry 2</option>
    </select>;
  }

  onIndustryChangeOption(event, index, value) {
    const {target} = event;
    const option = target.options[target.selectedIndex];
    if (option) {
      console.log(option.getAttribute('data-industry'));
      //this.props.setRootState({selectedIndustry: event.target.value});
    }
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

---

That said, with the given example, it's not clear why you wouldn't use `value` instead. :-)

Comment: can I store objects into value?

Comment: @Mizlul - No, but you can't store objects in `data-*` attributes, either. Attributes contain strings.

Comment: is there any possibilities that we can store objects as well?

Comment: would storing it as a json string and then convert back to javascript object be a good idea? I mean is this reliable?

Comment: i think this needs a separate question, since I am limited to make questions for 1.5h, would be great if you could shortly answer this if thats a way how to do or is it just a hack and not reliable!

Comment: @Mizlul - (Agreed on it being a separate question. Too bad about the rate-limit, in this case.) You *could* do that, or you could use `value` to store a key, and use it to look up the relevant object which you've stored in an array or object or `Map`, which is probably what I'd do.

Answer (score -2):

Simply pass callback reference and capture event, use `value` attribute

```js
<select onChange={this.onIndustryChangeOption} value={this.props.selectedIndustry}>
    <option value="industry1">Industry 1</option>
    <option value="industry2" >Industry 2</option>
</select>

onIndustryChangeOption(event) {
   this.props.setRootState({selectedIndustry: event.target.value});
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer question how to access data attribute on selected `<option>`

Comment: Sometimes answer is an alternate way of achieving the output